# HeadJS and jQuery Usage

Tags: jquery

Trying to use http://headjs.com for a while now but I haven't still because I can't fully understand the limited documentation and samples. If you can give examples of HeadJS with some jQuery that would be great.

Currently, this is what I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
.....
.....
<script src="js/jQuery.plugins.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jQuery.plugins.2.js"></script>
<!--
    Below are inline and cannot be a separate JS
    file because of CMS and templating limitation
//-->
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.class').someEffect();
    // Too many more code here
});
</script>
<!-- End inline scripts //-->
</body>
</html>
```

My questions:

1. If I'll use HeadJS,  where should I put the **jQuery.noConflict();** now? Or will there be no more conflicts even if I'll use another JS library?
2. Where to put my inline scripts, in **head.ready()**? Do the the '**$**' sign will not cause any conflicts with other libraries?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing the point of Head JS. Here's what your `<head>` element should look like:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="path/to/head.js"></script>

    <script>
    // files are loaded in parallel and executed in order they arrive
    head.js('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js')
        .js('path/to/other/external.js'),
        .js('and/so/on');

    // Call a function after all scripts have been loaded and the document is scriptable
    head.ready(function ()
    {
        jQuery.noConflict();

        // do your inline stuff with $ (Prototype, not jQuery)
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Btw, as I have commented in the code above I can't save the inline scripts as a separate JS file, it has to be inline.

Comment: @bloggerious: why do you need `jQuery.noConflict()` at all?

Comment: because I will also use Prototype library and will also have some inline Protype scripts to be there.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src='/js/head.js'></script>
        <!--
            Below are inline and cannot be a separate JS
            file because of CMS and templating limitation
        -->
        <script>
            head.js('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1/prototype.js', '/js/jQuery.plugins.1.js', '/js/jQuery.plugins.2.js', function($, $P) {
                return function() {
                    // $:  jQuery
                    // $P: Prototype
                    $('.class').someEffect();
                    // …
                };
            }(jQuery, _$));
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- your HTML code goes here -->
    </body>
</html>​​
```

---

I'll explain some things there.

```
head.js(…, function($, $P) {
    return function() {
        …
    };
}(jQuery, _$));
```

It's almost the same as anonymous functions, except they won't get executed instantly. In this example, it gets executed when all scripts are loaded.

If you load jQuery on a site that's already using `$`, it stores the original `$` in the `_$` variable, this is why it can restore the original `$` with `jQuery.noConflict()`.

```
noConflict: function( deep ) {
    window.$ = _$;

    if ( deep ) {
        window.jQuery = _jQuery;
    }

    return jQuery;
},
```