# head.js and jQuery $.noConflict() not Working as Expected

Tags: jquery, head.js

I'm trying to figure out why this works:

```
<script src="js/head.js"></script>
<script>head.js(<import-several-libraries-here>);</script>

<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    var j183 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

but these don't:

```
<script src="js/head.js"></script>

<script>
    head.js(<import-several-libraries-here>);
    head.js("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js");
    head.js("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js");

    var j183 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

**AND**

```
<script src="js/head.js"></script>

<script>
    head.js(<import-several-libraries-here>);
    head.js("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js");
    head.js("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js");
</script>

<script>
    var j183 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

I've read this and tried variations, to no avail:

[HeadJS and jQuery Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033878/headjs-and-jquery-usage)

**UPDATE**

I tried a suggested answer:

```
head.js("http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js");
head.js("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js", function() {
            var j183 = $.noConflict(true);
        });
```

and it didn't work.

Comment: I'm just going to take a guess and say that in your two examples that don't work, the "var j183" assignment part is getting executed before head.js loads the libraries you've specified.  Try adding that "var j183" part to a separate js file, and load it via head.js after your libraries and see what happens.

Comment: This seemed like a good guess...  I tried it and it didn't yield any good results.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to leave out text/JavaScript for brevity, you can forget it altogether, it's been deprecated in html5 and before that never really ever served a purpose unless set to something different anyways. Same goes for text/css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://headjs.com/

Maybe you should try something like this which will load the two jQuery libraries, and then call the anonymous function, which re-assigns the jQuery library to the global variable for use later.

```
<script src="js/head.js"></script>

<script>
    head.js(<import-several-libraries-here>);

    head.js("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js", 
            "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js", function() {

         window.j183 = $.noConflict(true);

         head.js(<import-several-libraries-here>, function(){
            init();
         });  //that depend on j183

    });

    function init(){
         var $ = window.j183;

         $('body').each(function(){
             //do something
         });

         j183('body').each(function(){
             //do something else
         });

    }
</script>
```

**Updated:** to show how to init the library.

Comment: In this case do I have to use `window.j183` in place of `$` or just `j183`?

Comment: just `j183` which should reference by default `window.j183` unless the function scope stack also has a reference to `j183`.

if you want to create a function scoped version of jQuery you can assign it to the `$` like i have updated the above example.

Comment: after some fiddling, I got this to work, your original solution.  No init() function...  Just head.js and a callback to the var... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute any code that relies on dependencies load via head.js in a callback:

```
head.js("/path/to/jquery.js", function() {

   var j183 = $.noConflict(true);

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I added the code you suggested and the target script still didn't work.  Just to be sure, I went back to what I claimed worked above, and it did still work, so I'm still stuck...  Thanks!

Comment: this will create `j183` as a local object within the function scope, i think he needs it as a global object for other code to work.